# Linked account with > 200 rep not showing in Area51

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

My Area51 account is linked to my SO and SE accounts correctly when I click on my 'Accounts' tab. Plus, I have over 200 reputation on SO, yet it is not showing around Area51. As far as I understand, all that is needed for your SO/SE accounts to show up in Area51 is

- they need to be linked properly and
- only accounts with at least 200 reputation will show up

Am I missing something?

PS, I've seen a lot of threads about this but couldn't find my answer. I wouldn't be the least bit offended if you close this question as a duplicate, assuming you can point me towards a thread that indeed is a duplicate and answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you just hit the 200 reputation mark today.  Area 51 only syncs reputation from other sites nightly, so you should see it start showing up tomorrow.  If not, we have a bug :)

Comment: I did indeed just cross the 200 mark today. I never saw that little tidbit about syncing in the FAQs or threads. Thanks!