# If I committed before I had a 200 rep, will my over 200 rep count?

Tags: support, area-51

When my rep in Stack Exchange is over 200, should I uncommit, then commit in Area51?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you do not have to recommit to proposals on Area51. You account will automatically be accounted for in the *"committers with 200+ rep on any other site"* list once you hit 200 rep in any site.

However, do note that it may take up to a day for that to happen as [the reps are synced nightly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71465/linked-account-with-200-rep-not-showing-in-area51/71467#71467).